# Unable to import data into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, import

I am trying to create a method that will import data into 2 dimensional array.  But somehow my method doesn't work and I found out that the code went wrong after the line:

```
while (dataScan.hasNext())
```

Example of .txt file intending for import:

```
##mm1.0

RowCount=10
--/20140925/Grocery/Supermarket/-5.23/600.00
--/20141013/Car Maintenance/Changing Tires/-200.00/500.00
```

I want to have the code the read each of them into array, if the line starts with "--"

```
public TablePanel()
{

    data = new Object[10][5];


}


public void openData()
{

    //Initializing Variables and set up directory
    fileChooser = new JFileChooser(userDirectory);
    //Set File Filter
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);


    //It will return positive if user decides to save 
    //null means that the dialog won't be open according
    //to specific Frame
    int valReturn = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    try { //Need to catch IO Exception here

        if (valReturn == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            //Get the selected file into the File
            //and initializing the BufferReader to read the content
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            BufferedReader bufferR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            //Inputting it into Scanner class for parsing tokens
            Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(bufferR);


            //Perform the following as long as Scanner class has next
            String currentLine;
            String dataLine;
            Scanner dataScan;
            //rowData is for importing data and counting rows
            int rowData = 0;

            while (fileScan.hasNext())
            {

                //Putting it into current line 
                currentLine = fileScan.nextLine();




                //Perform the following if the line starts with "--"
                if (currentLine.regionMatches(0, "--", 0, 2)) 
                {

                    //cutting the "--" from the line
                    dataLine = currentLine.substring(1);

                    dataScan = new Scanner(dataLine);
                    //Separate them by "/"
                    dataScan.useDelimiter("/");
                    //putting data into data[][]

                    //Some problem with the following loops 
                    while (dataScan.hasNext())
                    {


                        for (int colData = 0; colData < data[0].length; rowData++)
                            data[rowData][colData] = dataScan.next();



                    }  //End of importing data per line

                    //increasing rowData by one
                    rowData++;


                } //End of data[][] import loop

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your fileScanner is based on the default WhiteSpace Pattern

```
Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(bufferR); //Replace this with
Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(bufferR, Pattern.compile(System.lineSeparator()); //Java7
```

Comment: I add this into my source code but it causes error.  I found out the solution though -- on the loop: for (int colData = 0; colData < data[0].length; rowData++)  It's supposed to be colData++ rather than rowData++.  Nonetheless, I thank you for taking time out and read my codes.  And I appreciate your help ^_^